# D3js v3 to v5 upgrade: unable to convert strings to integers

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I had a D3js code which produces bar graphs and works fine with version 3.x. I wanted to upgrade the code to version 5 in the interest of being updated. Upon doing so I was able to correct a number of syntax updates such as `scaleLinear`, `scaleBand`, etc. The data is imported via tsv. The code is able to show the graph on the page with the correct x axis widths for the bars. However, the yAxis bars go out of bounds and the scale on the y-axis is very short. For example, the data shows the maximum value of the data to be 30000, but the yaxis is only from 0-90. Upon further investigation the d.RFU values from which the y data is generated seems to be not converted from string to integers. In the v3 code, I had a function at the end which converted the type of d.RFU to integer using the unary operator 
`d.RFU = +d.RFU`

However, it seems to be not working in v5. Could this be due to the promises implementation in replacement of the asynchronous code? 
Any solutions on how to fix this in version 5?

Please let me know if you need any more information and forgive me if I have missed out anything as I am new to programming and this website. Any help is appreciated.

Here is parts of the code which I have right now:

```
  //set dimensions of SVG and margins
  var margin = { top: 30,  right: 100,  bottom: 50,   left: 100,  },
    width = divWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    x = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([0, width - 20], 0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height,0]); 
  //setup the axis
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);  
  var svg = d3.select("#bargraphID")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right - 100)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom - 10)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate (" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.tsv(filename).then(function(data) {
    // get x values from the document id
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
      return d.ID;
    }));
    yMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.RFU;
    });
    // get the y values from the document RFU tab
    y.domain([0, yMax]);

 //create the x-axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate (0, " + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("dx", "0em")
      .attr("dy", "-0.55em")
      .attr("y", 30)
      .attr("class", "x-axisticks");


  //create the y-axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);          

    //add the data as bars
    var bar = svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .style("fill", barColor)
      .attr("fill-opacity", "0.3")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.ID);
      })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      //set initial coords for bars for animation.
      .attr("y", height)
      .attr("height", 0)
      //animate bars to final heights
      .transition()
      .duration(700)
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.RFU);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.RFU);
        })
      .attr("fill-opacity", "1.0")
      .attr("class", "y-data");

 });

  //convert RFU to integers
  function type(d) {
    d.RFU = +d.RFU;
    return d;
  }
```

Comment: By chance did you follow an upgrade guide of sorts? I'm going to be attempting an upgrade from d3 v3.5.16 to latest v5 before long and anything to help make it less painless would be super helpful...especially since it would encompass multiple chart types.

Comment: Hi @ChrisW. I came across this guide https://iros.github.io/d3-v4-whats-new/  which does an excellent job of telling you what has changed between v3 to v4. v4 to v5 the big change was the promises, so v4 code should be easy to upgrade to v5.

Comment: You're my hero! Haven't started yet and thankful to see this before I do for a pretty darn well organized checklist and it's coming soon so the timing is awesome. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like with the old v3 and v4 versions, you have to pass the row conversion function to `d3.tsv` in D3 v5:

```
d3.tsv(filename, type)
```

Then, use the promise with `then`. Have in mind that `d3.tsv` always return strings (be it D3 v3, v4 or v5), [because](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parse):

> If a row conversion function is not specified, field values are strings.

Here is the demo with fake data:

```js
var tsv = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
  `name RFU
  foo 12
  bar 42
  baz 17`
]));

d3.tsv(tsv, type).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})

function type(d) {
  d.RFU = +d.RFU;
  return d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

PS: Since SO snippet may have a problem loading that blob in some browsers, here is the same code in JSFiddle, check the console: https://jsfiddle.net/kv0ea0x2/

Comment: Thank you so much. That really helped. I am loving D3js and the community is so helpful. But most of the tutorials are with v3 and often times they don't go into details like this haha. Thanks again.

Comment: Look for tutorials using v4, since it's almost identical to v5. Also, don't rely on tutorials, read the API.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. I look for tutorials first because some of them make it easier to understand the lingo. But I am getting acquainted with the API now more and more. I did the changes from v3 to v5 largely based on the API as there are no good tutorials for that.